# Error Refreshing List in Rally Connector for Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, rally

I am trying to use the [Rally Connector for Visual Studio](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/8346D3B6-63F1-4F2F-9C2E-02580B384FC7) (with Visual Studio 2010 Pro SP1) and getting the following error when the connector tries to refresh the list 1) after successfully logging in or 2) when clicking Refresh List:

> Unable to load data for Iterations filter drop-down due to a recent error. Please click "Refresh List" to reload list.

Again, clicking Refresh List simply yields the same error.

I am using version 1.6.5 of the connector.

I will pursue support from Rally if necessary once I get a chance; in the meantime, [searching](https://prod.help.rallydev.com/search/site/visual%20studio%20connector%20error) the [Rally Knowledge Base](https://prod.help.rallydev.com/rally-support-knowledge-base) didn't seem to yield anything related to the error; a [web search](http://www.bing.com/search?setmkt=en-US&q=Error%20Refreshing%20List%20in%20Rally%20Connector%20for%20Visual%20Studio) turned up nothing useful; and I have replied to a related question (regarding the error with an earlier version(s) of the connector) in the Visual Studio Gallery page linked above.  Basically I am trying to work this from all reasonable angles.

Here is what I see in the connector activity log (with the workspace value replaced in logged URLs for obvious reasons):

```
4/24/2013 8:23:35 PM  Sent request to load Tasks
4/24/2013 8:23:36 PM  Got response to load Tasks
4/24/2013 8:23:36 PM  Sent request to get all iterations in workspace https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.15/workspace/9876543210
4/24/2013 8:23:36 PM  Got response to get all iterations in workspace https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.15/workspace/9876543210
4/24/2013 8:23:37 PM  Warning: Following exception was thrown during getting distinct Iterations:
System.OverflowException: Value was either too large or too small for an Int32.
   at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
   at RallyConnector.RallyLoader.GetDistinctIterations(DataSet ds)
Code resumed with duplicate Iterations.
```

When I login to Rally through my browser, I do indeed see iterations with the same names; but those iterations are for different projects; and I certainly don't see an iteration count to overflow a 32-bit integer.  I would expect that whatever has been entered into Rally through browsers would work just fine with the connector.

Can duplicate iteration names really be the problem, or is something else at play?  Has anyone encountered and managed to resolve this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for the difficulty.

This error “Unable to load data for Iterations filter drop-down due to a recent error. Please click Refresh List to reload list”. And usually the "Refresh List" action will not fix the issue. This is a known issue which should be resolved for version >= 1.6.4 of the plugin. If you were running a previous version of the add-in you may need to do a clean reinstall (after uninstalling your present instance) in order to overcome this error.

A clean reinstall is the key - in my experience clean reinstall of the version 1.6.4 or higher always fixed this problem.

Before you re-install , please follow these steps to uninstall your current instance:

1. Close Visual Studio
2. Uninstall the current Visual Studio plugin
3. (Control Panel >> Add-Remove Programs)
4. In a Windows Explorer window,
   navigate to (example from Windows 7):
   "C:\Users\username\Documents\" (or the equivalent folder for your
   version of Windows)
5. Delete the folder named "RallyPlugin" from the "Documents" folder.

Please followup if this fails to resolve the issue.

Comment: Excellent.  That worked.  I read a bit about cleanly installing 1.6.5 after initially installing and encountering the issue with 1.6.3...but was under the impression that the 1.6.5 MSI would cleanly remove 1.6.3 based on the [Installation & User Guide](https://prod.help.rallydev.com/rally-plugin-microsoft-visual-studio-tfs-installation-user-guide). What no +1 for the effort of writing the question? ;)  Thanks.

Comment: Glad that sorted it out! Based on your feedback I'll coordinate with the documentation team to outline the steps for a clean uninstall within the installation and user guide. +1 :)